# insert an infotext for an online action in header

Tags: magento2, header

I want offer an online action and want insert a informationtext in the header of my website https://agoshop.at like in this picture:

[image: website with action text in header]

Hope someone can help me how I can solve this.
kindly regards for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow This :

**Step : 1**

In order to add HTML block at the top of the page please go to **Admin Panel > Content > Blocks** and press the **Add New Block button**.

Then Enable the block, set its **Title** and unique **Identifier**. Choose what Store View will your block be enabled on.

Afterward, in WYSIWYG editor create a code you want to be inserted at the top of the page of your website and press the Save Block button.

Example:

```
<div style="padding: 14px; text-align: center; background: #d7244e; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; border-top: 3px solid #f28d49;">Valentine's Day Sale. Get 15% OFF for <a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: underline;" href="#">ALL Magento 2 extensions</a>. Use coupon code <span style="text-decoration: underline;">VALENTINE2019</span></div>
```

[image]

**Step : 2**

After that go to **Admin Panel > Content > Widgets** and press the **Add New Widget button**.

Begin the configurations of the widget by setting its **Type** and **Design Theme**. Press the **Continue** button to move further.

[image]

In the Layout Updates section, you have to choose the exact place you want your block to be displayed on. Select **All Pages** to display it on all pages and choose Page Top as the block container to position it at the top of the page.
[image]
Widget Options choose the **CMS block** to be displayed with the widget and press the **Save and Continue Edit** button
[image]

**Step : 3**
Cache Flush

You can see now :
[image]

Comment: Hi!
Thanks a lot for the brilliant answer and tutorial.
kindly regards

Comment: Great !! Please vote up Thanks